# How to upload a QRCode to itunesconnect while submitting app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My app uses QRcode for login. I am going to submit my app to apps store how i can provide QRcode to Apple for demo account. So that they can test and verify the app.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you put in on a website or even something like imgur and give them the URL ?

Answer (score 0):

Put a link to the QRCode you want them to demo with on the review information section of your submission. (You'll need to upload the QRCode to the cloud and have it publicly accessible).